# Proof by induction - stuck on simple question!

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing, induction

Question:

(**Part 1**) Show that the inequality 
$$
\frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(n-1)\cdot n} < \frac{1}{2}
$$ 
works for all natural numbers $n > 2$.

(**Part 2**) Deduce that for all natural numbers $n$, the following inequality holds:
$$
\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{7}{4}.
$$

This is a problem I found when rummaging around through old proof by induction questions and has been quite an issue for me. You see, I struggled with the first part, I proved it works for $n=3$ and then wrote out the result for $n=k$ and $n=k+1$ but I couldn't progress from there.

What I did:

- When $n = 3$: 
  $$
  \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} = \frac{1}{6}
  $$
  and since $1/6 < 1/2$,  the proposition is true for $n=3$.
- Assuming the truth of the proposition when $n = k$ i.e. 
  $$
  \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(k-1)\cdot k} < \frac{1}{2}
  $$
  and considering $n = k+1$, prove that
  $$
  \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(k+1)\cdot k} < \frac{1}{2}
  $$
  From there I couldn't seem to find a way to link the assumption into the $n=k+1$ inequality in order to prove that that is also $< 1/2$.

Can't solve the first part in order to link to the second part in order to fulfill the "deduce" part.
Thanks in advance and sorry if it's just a stupid error I've made.

Comment: Your question is difficult to read, please use MathJax.

Comment: You can't really use induction directly, because for the induction hypothesis, all you know is that the sum up to $k$ is smaller than $\frac12$, you don't know anything about _how much_ smaller. So you need to actually make a _stronger_ statement ($<\frac12-{}$ something) in order to give yourself some wiggle room. Or you could guess what the sum _actually_ is, and prove that using induction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$No need for induction here. Just note that\begin{align}\frac1{2\times3}+\frac1{3\times3}+\cdots+\frac1{(n-1)n}&=\frac12-\cancel{\frac13}+\cancel{\frac13}+\cdots-\cancel{\frac1{n-1}}+\cancel{\frac1{n-1}}-\frac1n\\&=\frac12-\frac1n\\&<\frac12.\end{align}And then\begin{align}\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}&<1+\frac14+\frac1{2\times3}+\cdots+\frac1{n(n-1)}\\&<1+\frac14+\frac12\\&=\frac74.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense now but I still don't understand one thing, I see how  1/2 x 3 = 1/2 - 1/3 but how did you derive this rule, is it something I should know? And does it only work for consecutive numbers like in this case?

Comment: I simply used the equality$$\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac1{n(n+1)}.$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hints**:

$1.\qquad\dfrac1{2\cdot 3}=\dfrac12-\dfrac 13,\quad \dfrac1{3\cdot 4}=\dfrac 13-\dfrac14,\;\dots,\;\dfrac1{(n -1)n}=\dfrac1{n-1}-\dfrac 1n$.

$2.\qquad \dfrac1{3^2}<\dfrac 1{2\cdot 3},\quad \dfrac1{4^2}<\dfrac1{3\cdot4},\;\dots\;,\dfrac1{n^2}<\dfrac1{(n-1)n}.$